# Apply Lightbox or similar pop up effect to an image array, or more specifically, JQuery Reel

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I am trying to use JQuery Reel to produce an animation that will run within an iPhone app.

It is in early development stages, but I do seem to have come across a problem.

The idea is that when the user clicks (or touches in this case) the image currently displayed within the reel, the standard lightbox effect takes place, enlarging the image to give more information/larger image etc...

I have no idea how to get this to work without breaking the existing code. At the very least it would be great if the images clicked could be links.

You can find where [I am at here](http://www.studioleach.com/reel/example/with-white.html)

Any help or pointers would be great!

Cheers guys.

Answer (score 0):

Matt,

Reel doesn't support binding to `"click"` event directly yet. But since Reel wraps the `IMG` in question in a DIV, which acts as an overlay to the image, you can bind `"click"` to it and it would work without affecting the underlaying Reel.

When you initiate Reel like this:

```
$('#my_image').reel()
```

You can then bind click to it this way:

```
$('#my_image').parent().click(function(){
    /* Your click handler code */
});
```

This however has a drawback - the click will happen regardless of any dragging in between mouse press and release. So having a possibility to properly bind click to the Reel image would be a cool improvement and I will consider it for future releases.

Happy Reeling!